# react export basic component not rendering

Tags: reactjs

I am testing some react component basic functionality, just exporting an `<hr/>`

this is my component:

```
import React from 'react'
export default () => {
    return(
        <hr/>
    ) 
}
```

But that is not rendering on the file I'm calling it,

```
const linea = require('./Linea')
function App(){
  return (
    <div>
      <p>tkt</p>
      <linea/>
      <hr/>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App
```

What is missing to show the line? cheers

Comment: components in react are camelcased like `<Linea/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example based on your code

[Code Sandbox working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-hawking-izgok?file=/src/index.js)

```
import React from "react";
export default function Linea() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>rendered child Linea</h1>
      <hr />
    </>
  );
}
```

and in the parent

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Linea from "./Linea";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Linea/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```